# Microsoft Access Validation Formula

Tags: windows, validation, ms-access, formula

In ms access, how to write a validation formula for maximum of two letters in a field, first one being a letter and the second one being a number?

E.g. A9 (allowed)
     B5 (allowed)
     BB5 (not accepted)
     DD (not accepted)    23 (not accepted)

Comment: Are you trying to validate cell indices? If so, `A42` would be valid, too, just like `AA1`.

Comment: Oh no. Just trying to have a maximum of two letters. Just the first one being an alphabet and the second being the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting the Validation Rule for the field at table level to the following should work:

```
IS NULL OR Like "[A-Z]#"
```

This will accept characters between A and Z for the first character and the `#` is to accept numbers in the second character space. I added the `Is Null Or` but you may want to remove it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I will check whether this works or not and I will let you know.. Thanks you very much for the answer